# Clean, Modular Code vs MV* Frameworks

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, angularjs, mvvm, knockout.js

I've been hearing a-lot about the "new" MV* frameworks. I've tinkered with KnockoutJS, creating an invoicing application, but I much prefer to write clean, modular code in raw JavaScript - leveraging utility APIs and other libraries *when necessary*.

Given a methodical/structured/SOLID approach to writing a JavaScript application, where OOP, SOC, SRP and other design principles are adhered to, wouldn't the usage of MV* frameworks be superfluous?

Are there any articles that express/address these concerns?

*I've found one in the past:*

http://www.netmagazine.com/opinions/dont-get-tied-one-javascript-framework

Answer (score 2):

If you write good, clean, modular code, you'll find that you repeat a lot of patterns and maybe even copy a lot of boilerplate code from past projects. You'll eventually end up with your own personal framework of sorts.

*Every* clean, modular application like you've described has some kind of framework behind it, be it a reusable third-party framework or something that evolves with/underneath the app. Many developers find they save time and have a *better* framework if they use somebody else's.

Comment: Adding to @trevor answer, chances of you making mistakes while creating such a implementation\framwork is less as compared to already tried and tested frameworks. Eventually you would have to fix all issues that come as part of your own implementation.

Comment: you're right about repeating patterns, that's what a pattern is, something that's repeated. software design patterns are tried & true methods for writing code. i do end up re-using bits/pieces of said code in other applications. how is that different from an opinionated framework like angular or knockout, where they're re-used in app-to-app? other than the fact that their heavier and contain features i'd likely never use? Or, justify using said framework because i wanted to use two-way binding on a few forms. not trying to bash your answer, but you're echoing arguments i've heard before.

Answer (score 0):

Knockout is very modular but also very maintainable. For example the bindingHandler pattern makes it very easy to extend the library with jQUery UI, etc

MVVM is just a pattern that glues the View and the View logic (ViewModel) together in a decoupled way (If you do it correctly). You still gain from modularity, OOP etc So you can keep doing what you did in the past, just better.